# Print HTML tables with information from some devices

Tags: javascript, beginner

I'm not sure if this is the right question but didn't come up with something else. I have this huge `for{}` loop which prints out some HTML Tables with some infos from some devices.

This code looked totally wrong to me and it had bugs. I tried to make it look as idiomatic to JavaScript as possible (started learning JS 4 months ago) but I don't know if what I did is ok.

I know my code has several lines, but they are repeating in most cases.

Can anybody tell me if this code can be rewritten (or some parts of it) in a more proper way? (PS: the code is running as it is now, but I'm just trying to improve my JavaScript coding style)

```
for (controller in k) {
    controller = k[controller];
    try {
        newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['temperature'] = newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['temperature'] / 10;
        newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'] = newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'].split('*');

        if (!$('#controls_' + controller).length) {
            $('#controls').html($('#controls').html() + '<center id="controls_' + controller + '"></center>');
        }

        if ($('#' + controller + '_di').length) {
            $('#di_' + controller + '_head').html('');
            $('#di_' + controller + '_head').html('<th>' + newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][6] + '</th><th>' + newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][7] + '</th><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][8] + '</th><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][9] + '</th>');

            $('#di_' + controller + '_body').html('');
            var data = newMessage.args.info[controller].data.dynamic;
            var $target = $('#di_' + controller + '_body');

            if (controller === "lan_control_1") {
                if (data.phase1 === "up") color1 = '#D60B0B';
                else color1 = '#14B514';

                if (data.phase2 === "up") color2 = '#D60B0B';
                else color2 = '#14B514';

                if (data.phase3 === "up") color3 = '#D60B0B';
                else color3 = '#14B514';

                if (data.phase4 === "up") color4 = '#000000';
                else color4 = '#000000';
            } else {
                if (data.phase1 === "up") color1 = '#14B514';
                else color1 = '#D60B0B';

                if (data.phase2 === "up") color2 = '#14B514';
                else color2 = '#D60B0B';

                if (data.phase3 === "up") color3 = '#14B514';
                else color3 = '#D60B0B';

                if (data.phase4 === "up") color4 = '#000000';
                else color4 = '#000000';
            }

            var html = '<tr>' +
                '<td class="text-center"><font color="' + color1 + '">' + data.phase1 + '</font></td>' +
                '<td class="text-center"><font color="' + color2 + '">' + data.phase2 + '</font></td>' +
                '<td class="text-center"><font color="' + color3 + '">' + data.phase3 + '</font></td>' +
                '<td class="text-center"><font color="' + color4 + '">' + data.phase4 + '</font></td>' +
                '</tr>';

            $target.html(html);
        } else {
            $('#controls_' + controller).html($('#controls_' + controller).html() +
                '<span style="display: inline-table;"><table id="' +
                controller +
                '_di" class="table table-condensed table-bordered" width="100%"><thead><tr><th colspan="5"><center>Voltage (' +
                controller +
                ')</center></th></tr><tr id="di_' +
                controller +
                '_head"><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][6] +
                '</th><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][7] +
                '</th><th>' + newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][8] +
                '</th><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][9] +
                '</th></tr></thead><tbody id="di_' +
                controller +
                '_body"><tr><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['phase1'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['phase2'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['phase3'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['phase4'] +
                '</td></tr></tbody></table></span>');
        }

        if ($('#' + controller + '_do').length) {
            $('#do_' + controller + '_head').html('');
            $('#do_' + controller + '_head').html(newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['out0_descr']);

            console.log("here15" + newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['out0_descr']);
            console.log('\nPause\n');
            $('#do_' + controller + '_body').html('');

            var $target1 = $('#do_' + controller + '_body');

            if (controller === "lan_control_0") {
                if (['on', 'off'][newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['digital_out_0']] === "off") color5 = '#14B514';
                else color5 = '#D60B0B';
            } else {
                if (['on', 'off'][newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['digital_out_0']] === "off") color5 = '#000000';
                else color5 = '#000000';
            }
            console.log("here16" + newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['digital_out_0']);
            console.log('\nPause\n');

            var html1 = '<tr>' +
                '<td class="text-center"><font color="' + color5 + '">' + ['on', 'off'][newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['digital_out_0']] + '</font></td>' +
                '</tr>';
            $target1.html(html1);
        } else {
            $('#controls_' + controller).html($('#controls_' +
                    controller).html() +
                '<span style="display: inline-table;"><table id="' +
                controller +
                '_do" class="table table-condensed table-bordered" width="100%"><thead><tr><th colspan="2"><center id="do_' +
                controller +
                '_head">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['out0_descr'] +
                ' (' +
                controller +
                ')</center></th></tr><tr><th>Value</th></tr></thead><tbody id="do_' +
                controller +
                '_body"><tr><td>' + ['on', 'off'][newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['digital_out_0']] +
                '</td></tr></tbody></table></span>');
        }

        if ($('#' + controller + '_t').length) {
            $('#t_' + controller + '_head').html('');
            if (controller === "lan_control_0") {
                $('#t_' + controller + '_head').html('<th>Temp_Amb<sup>Lab Et.-1</sup></th><th>Humidity<sup>Lab Et.-1</sup> [ % ]</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][0] +
                    '</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][1] +
                    '</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][2] +
                    '</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][3] +
                    '</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][4] +
                    '</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][5] +
                    '</th>');
            } else {
                $('#t_' + controller + '_head').html('<th>Temp_Amb<sup>Lab Et.1</sup></th><th>Humidity<sup>Lab Et.1</sup> [ % ]</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][0] +
                    '</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][1] +
                    '</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][2] +
                    '</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][3] +
                    '</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][4] +
                    '</th><th>' +
                    newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][5] +
                    '</th>');
            }

            $('#t_' + controller + '_body').html('');
            $('#t_' + controller + '_body').html('<tr><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['temperature'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['humidity'] / 10 +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t0'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t1'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t2'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t3'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t4'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t5'] +
                '</td></tr>');
        } else {
            $('#controls_' + controller).html($('#controls_' + controller).html() +
                '<span style="display: inline-table;"><table id="' +
                controller +
                '_t" class="table table-condensed table-bordered" width="100%"><thead><tr><th colspan="8"><center>Temperature (' +
                controller +
                ')</center></th></tr><tr id="t_' +
                controller + '_head"><th>T</th><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][0] +
                '</th><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][1] +
                '</th><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][2] +
                '</th><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][3] +
                '</th><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][4] +
                '</th><th>' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['static']['di_ia_descr'][5] +
                '</th></tr></thead><tbody id="t_' +
                controller +
                '_body"><tr><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['temperature'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t0'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t1'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t2'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t3'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t4'] +
                '</td><td class="text-center">' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['t5'] +
                '</td></tr></tbody></table></span>');
        }

        var timestamp = new Date(0);
        timestamp.setUTCSeconds(parseInt(newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['timestamp']));
        if ($('#' + controller + '_state').length) {
            $('#' + controller + '_state').html('');
            $('#' + controller + '_state').html('<p><a href="' + newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['url'] + '">' + controller + '</a>:: ' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['uptime_days'] + ' days, ' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['uptime_hours'] + ' hours, ' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['uptime_minutes'] + ' minutes, ' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['uptime_seconds'] + ' seconds; ' + '</p>');
        } else {
            $('#controls_status').html($('#controls_status').html() +
                '<span id="' +
                controller +
                '_state"><p><a href="' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['url'] +
                '">' +
                controller +
                '</a>:: ' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['uptime_days'] + ' days, ' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['uptime_hours'] + ' hours, ' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['uptime_minutes'] + ' minutes, ' +
                newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic']['uptime_seconds'] + ' seconds; ' +
                timestamp + '</p></span>');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('[MAINWEBSOCKET] on message error: ' + err);
    }
}
```

One problem that I could have is that if I ever would like to modify those tables, I won't be able without rewriting everything again.

To make yourself an idea of how the HTML looks like, here is an image:

[image: image description could be put here]

Comment: As we all want to improve our code, it is better to write a title that says something about what your code does. I have made an edit to it, feel welcome to review it. I hope you get some good answers!

Comment: Got it ! Thanks @Phrancis. You're right, will keep that in mind.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 5 to 4. Please read [What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is use a reference to that long property chain `newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']`. You already do it in one instance:

```
var dynamicData = newMessage['args']['info'][controller]['data']['dynamic'];
```

Also use the dot notation instead of the bracket notation when you have a string (containing a JS identifier) as the property. The first line then becomes much more readable

```
dynamicData.temperature = dynamicData.temperature / 10;
```

---

You should avoid appending to `.html()`. This is terribly slow, as this requires the browser the build a string from the DOM and then turn the whole thing back into a DOM structure. When adding a new element use `.append()` instead.

Also don't repeatedly get the same elements with jQuery. Store a reference and use that instead.

```
if (!$('#controls_' + controller).length) {
   $('#controls').html($('#controls').html() + '<center id="controls_' + controller + '"></center>');
}
```

becomes

```
var $controllerControls = $('#controls_' + controller);
if ($controllerControls.length === 0) {
    $controllerControls = $('<center id="controls_' + controller + '"></center>');
    $('#controls').append($controllerControls);
}
// From here on use $controllerControls instead of $('#controls_' + controller)
```

BTW, `center` is deprecated. Use a `div` (or preferably another suitable element) and use CSS to center it.

---

Instead of hard coding the colors in your code consider defining them in your style sheet and setting classes in your JS. This also gets rid of the `font` elements which are also deprecated.

Also, use loops where possible and avoid string concatenations, since they are also slow.

For example:

```
 var html = '<tr>' +
     '<td class="text-center"><font color="' + color1 + '">' + data.phase1 + '</font></td>' +
     '<td class="text-center"><font color="' + color2 + '">' + data.phase2 + '</font></td>' +
     '<td class="text-center"><font color="' + color3 + '">' + data.phase3 + '</font></td>' +
     '<td class="text-center"><font color="' + color4 + '">' + data.phase4 + '</font></td>' +
     '</tr>';
$target.html(html);
```

becomes something like:

```
var html = ["<tr>"];

for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    html.push('<td class="text-center ', data["phase" + i], i === 4 ? " black" : "",  '">', data.phase1, '</td>');                
}

html.push("</tr>")

$target.html(html.join(''));
```

With the CSS:

```
.up {
    color: #14B514;
}
.dn {
    color: #D60B0B
}
.up.black, .dn.black {
    color: black !important;
}
#di_lan_control_1_body .up {
    color: #D60B0B;
}
#di_lan_control_1_body .dn {
    color: #14B514;
}
```

(This isn't an exact copy. It strong depends things I don't know about. For example, `black` is a bad choice for the class name, it should be a word describing why `phase4` is different from the others.)

---

```
<span style="display: inline-table;"><table>...
```

This doesn't make much sense. For one, you aren't allowed to put a `table` inside a `span`. If you need an inline table, put `display: inline-table` directly on the table itself - best would be in the stylesheet.

---

Generally: consider using a templating library to generate the HTML. It always best to keep the JS separate from the HTML.

---

(That's all I have time for right now.)